# Couchbase - Bulk insert via Java

Tags: java, couchbase, bulkinsert

### Introduction

I am currently working on a Java project using Couchbase as a database. As part of it, I came to create a massive data insert via a json file and a csv file.

### Question

And I was wondering, what is the best way to achieve this one? Is it possible to have a sample code?

Comment: If you have a CSV file, you might want to consider using cbimport instead https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/tools/cbimport-csv.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to format the csv file before inserting it and report every wrong tuple. The project I'm in uses a Quarkus API for all interactions. I didn't have access to console on main server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## CSV conversion:

### Benchmark:

You have several libraries to perform the conversion between CSV <-> Java object, here is a benchmark of the different libraries:

| Library | Read (rec/sec) | Write (rec/sec) | Dependencies | Size (KiB) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Commons CSV | 1,128,102 | 3,354,703 | no | 50 |
| FastCSV | 4,738,726 | 5,034,953 | no | 31 |
| Jackson CSV | 3,770,602 | 3,995,294 | yes | 2,040 |
| Java CSV | 1,922,189 | 2,732,843 | no | 13 |
| Opencsv | 1,085,935 | 1,808,982 | yes | 2,625 |
| Sfm+ASM | 5,164,967 | 1,901,154 | yes | 1.498 |
| Sfm-ASM | 4,652,517 | 1,901,154 | yes | 1,498 |
| Super CSV | 1,406,090 | 1,730,984 | no | 96 |
| Univocity | 3,594,900 | 4,050,255 | no | 437 |

*For more information on this benchmark you can visit this site:  https://github.com/osiegmar/JavaCsvBenchmarkSuite#results*

### FastCSV:

Iterative reading of some CSV data with a header

```java
NamedCsvReader.builder().build("header 1,header 2\nfield 1,field 2")
    .forEach(row -> row.getField("header 2"));
```

*For more information about **FastCSV** you can visit this site: https://github.com/osiegmar/FastCSV*

---

## JSON conversion:

### Benchmark:

You have several libraries to perform the conversion between Json <-> Java object, here is a benchmark of the different libraries:

[image]

*For more information on this benchmark you can visit this site:  https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json*

### jackson-databind:

Conversion from json string to java object:

```java
String json = "{\"name\":\"Hassan\",\"age\":23}";
Person person = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Person.class);
```

*For more information about **jackson-databind** you can visit this site: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind*

---

## CouchBase insertion:

Example of Bulk Insert in Java:

```java
protected void doWork() {
    final String key = "javaDevguideExampleBulkInsert";
    // Create a JSON document content
    final JsonObject content = JsonObject.create().put("item", "A bulk insert test value");
    // Describe what we want to do asynchronously using RxJava Observables:
    ReactiveCollection reactiveCollection = collection.reactive();
    Flux<MutationResult> resultFlux = Flux.range(0, 10)
            .map(index -> { return key + "_" + index; })
            .flatMap(k -> reactiveCollection.upsert(k, content));
    resultFlux.subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

*This code is from [official **docs-sdk-java**](https://github.com/couchbase/docs-sdk-java/blob/7dc0cc29175a01b9db82c0d9920e582b04096491/modules/devguide/examples/BulkInsert.java#L37-L40) of CouchBase*